# How can I keep NAN values while I am extracting a subset?

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a dataframe and there is a column called 'budget'.
There are some NaN values in this column and I'd like to keep them.

However when I try to exclude a sub-frame in which the budget value is bigger than (or equal to) 38750, I lost my NaN values in the new data frame!

```
df2 = df[df.budget >= 38750]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a double condition, where the second condition checks whether the values in the budget column are missing:

```
inds = (df['budget'] >= 38750) | (df['budget'].isnull())
df2 = df.loc[inds, :]
```

Comment: `df.loc[inds]` suffices, it automatically takes all the columns